# DOJO Dialog Box - Issue

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dialog

I'm trying to use the dialog box in my application and having difficulties with adding javascript..

Sample Code -

```
var profileDialog1 = new Dialog({ 
    title: "Create Profile", 
    style: "width: 700px;height: 540px;", 
    href: "profile.html" });

domStyle.set(profileDialog1.containerNode,{ 
    position: 'relative'
});
```

In profile.html - i have HTML dom and also javascript and making calls to JS file and the methods in it.. 
Sample -

```
<div id="detailsDiv">666666666</div>

<script>alert("111");</script> <div id="modifyDetailsDiv"></div>
<script>
    alert("1"); 
    require([ "opstool/profile/profile" ], function(profile) { 
        var query = dojo.queryToObject(window.location.search.substring(1));
        alert("query.cidFlag - " + query.cidFlag); 
        alert("query.name - " + query.name);
        profile.displayProfileDetails("detailsDiv","modifyDetailsDiv",query.cidFlag,query.name); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Problem - 
   When i use the Dialog box, and include profile.html in href - None of the javascript functions are getting invoked and when i remove the Dialog box and use regular window.open() the javascript executes and the profile.html screen is painted with all the form fields..

I'm very much new to DOJO and learning it.. Please help if I'm doing something wrong..

Regards 
Snehal

Comment: Can I ask what `profile.dis` is? That line doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Comment: It is actually - profile.displayProfileDetails(...)

Comment: Probably work rewriting  the script to be more readable for folks who might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dojox.widget.DialogSimple it has a executescripts parameter

Comment: i tried using the DialogSimple but it is still not loading the script.. Sample Code -   var dlg = new dojox.widget.DialogSimple({ title:"Create Profile - H2H", 
   executeScripts:true, 
   style: "width: 700px;height: 540px;", 
   href:"profile.html" });
  dlg.startup();

Comment: There might be something failing in the script on the imported page,  I tried it with a simple page with just <script>alert('hello')</script>  and it ran the alert when the dialog came up